# Concat Multiple Select responses

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, group-concat

I am very new the DB scripting, but I have the following `Select` statements returning 3 different Data sets from 2 separate tables.

```
SELECT  
A.CustomerId,
C.Customername  
FROM   
BankCustomer C  
RIGHT JOIN  
BankAssociation A  
ON C.CustomerId = A.CustomerId 

SELECT 
A.TypeId,
T.Type 
FROM
BankAssociation A 
LEFT JOIN
BankTypes T 
On A.TypeId = T.TypeId 

SELECT 
A.CustomerId2,
C.Customername 
FROM
BankCustomer C 
RIGHT JOIN
BankAssociation A 
On C.CustomerId = A.CustomerId2
```

The multiple `SELECT`statements will return DATA in separate tables as such:

SELECT 1

```
Damian Wayne
Peter Parker
```

SELECT 2

```
CLEANS
BUILDS
```

SELECT 3

```
Bruce Wayne
Ben Parker
```

My question:
I want to concatenate the Rows with a verb that will display the Rows something like this

```
Damian Wayne CLEANS for Bruce Wayne
Peter Parker BUILDS for Ben Parker
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT CONCAT(C.CustomerName , ' ' , T.Type , ' for ' , C2.CustomerName ) FROM 
    BankAssociation A
    LEFT JOIN BankCustomer C  ON C.CustomerId = A.CustomerId 
    LEFT JOIN BankCustomer C2 ON C2.CustomerId = A.CustomerId2 
    LEFT JOIN BankTypes T On A.TypeId = T.TypeId
```